# How to not take empty line from tab when executing execvp

Tags: c, pointers, exec

I'm making a shell program which use execvp with a tab to execute my command.

If i put in the shell "ls -l;ls", it should exec "ls -l" (it work) then "ls" but it does "ls "

My tab will have [ls\0][-l\0], will exec perfectly

then if i try ls, my tab: [ls\0][\0] and it give me:

ls: cannot access: No such file or directory

How can I remove that last [\0] to only have [ls\0] in my tab?

Thanks

EDIT: here is the full code, can't make

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define syserror(x) perror(errormsg[x])
#define fatalsyserror(x) syserror(x), exit(x)
#define ROUGE(m) "\033[01;31m"m"\033[0m"
#define VERT(m) "\033[01;32m"m"\033[0m"
#define FAILEDEXEC 127
#define DONTEXEC 128
#define ERR -1
#define SIZECMDLINE 4096
#define SIZE 1024
#define MAXCMD 10
#define PIPEFAILED 1

typedef struct statusProc {
    int proc;
    int value;
    int failed;
} StatusProc;

StatusProc statusproc;

char * errormsg[] = {
    "No error",
    ROUGE("Impossible to fork process"),
    ROUGE("Exec failed")
};

void traiterCmdInFork(char *cmd[SIZE]){
    char *tab[SIZE],**ps;
    int i=0;
    tab[i]=cmd[i];
    i++;
    cmd++;
    for(;*cmd && *cmd!='\0';i++,cmd++){
        tab[i]=*cmd;
        cmd++;
    }
    for (ps = tab; *ps; ps++) printf("r:%s ", *ps);

    execvp(*tab, tab);
    syserror(2);
    exit(FAILEDEXEC);
}

int traiterInFather(char *cmd[SIZE]){


char currentdir[SIZE];
    if(!strncmp(*cmd,"cd",2)){
        chdir(*(cmd+1));
        getcwd(currentdir, SIZE);
        return 1;
    } else if(!strncmp(*cmd,"status",6)){
        if (!statusproc.proc){
            printf("Aucune commande execute avant\n");
        } else if(!statusproc.failed){
            printf("%d termine avec comme code retour %d\n",statusproc.proc,statusproc.value);
        } else {
            printf("%d termine anormalement\n",statusproc.proc);
        }
        return 1;
    }


return 0;
    }

int main(void) {
    char lgcmd[SIZECMDLINE], command[SIZE], *tabcmd[SIZE], currentdir[SIZE], *newcmd, *s, *tmp ,**ps;
    pid_t p;
    int i, j, nbcar, nbcmdprev, status, waitstatus, waitprev;
    nbcmdprev=0;

    //utiliser macro
    for(;;) {
        getcwd(currentdir, SIZE);
        printf("%s>",currentdir);
        memset(lgcmd,0,SIZECMDLINE);
        fgets(lgcmd, SIZECMDLINE-1, stdin);
        for(s=lgcmd; isspace(*s); s++);
        s[strlen(s)-1]='\0'; //retire \n a la fin de la ligne de commande
        printf("Command line:%s\n",s);

        nbcar=0;
        status=0;
        waitprev=0;
        waitstatus=0;
        i=0;
        newcmd=s;
        printf("test");
        for(;*s;s++,nbcar++){
            //on avance jusqua fin dune commande
            printf("R3");
            if(*s==';' || *(s+1)=='\0' || *s=='|' || *s=='&'){ //traiter cas || et && et finligne
                if(*s=='|' && *(s+1)=='|'){
                    *s++='\0';
                    waitprev=2;
                } else if(*s=='&' && *(s+1)=='&'){
                    *s++='\0';
                    waitprev=1;
                } else if(*(s+1)=='\0'){
                    s++;
                    nbcar++;
                }
                memset(command,0,strlen(command));
                for (j = 0; j < nbcmdprev; j++) {
                    memset(tabcmd[j],0,strlen(tabcmd[j]));
                    printf("clear %d\n",j);
                }
                memcpy(command,newcmd,nbcar);
                *s='\0';
                for(tmp=command; isspace(*tmp); tmp++);
                for(i=0; *tmp && tmp !=s; i++) {
                    tabcmd[i]=tmp;
                    //stopper le while quand on rencontre un ; ou & ou |
                    while (!isspace(*tmp) && *tmp!='\0' && *tmp!=';' && *tmp!='|' && *tmp!='&') {
                        printf("tmp:%c\n",*tmp);
                        tmp++;
                    }
                    //traiter &
                    if(*tmp=='|'){
                        waitprev=2;
                        *tmp++='\0';
                        break;
                    } else if(*tmp==';'){
                        waitprev=0;
                        *tmp++='\0';
                        break;
                    } else if(*tmp=='&'){
                        waitprev=1;
                        *tmp++='\0';
                        break;
                    } else if(*tmp!='\0'){
                        printf("tmp:%c\n",*tmp);
                        *tmp++='\0';
                    } else if(*tmp=='\0'){
                        printf("fin");
                    }
                    while (isspace(*tmp)) {
                        printf("tmp:%c\n",*tmp);
                        tmp++;
                    }
                    printf("tmp:%c\n",*tmp);
                }
                s++;
                newcmd=s;
                nbcar=0;
                nbcmdprev=i;
                if(!traiterInFather(tabcmd)){
                    printf("Dans if\n");
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        printf("len cmd%d:%d\n",j,strlen(*tabcmd));
                    }
                    p=fork();
                    if (p == ERR) fatalsyserror(1);
                    if(p) {
                        statusproc.proc=p;
                        wait(&status);
                        if(WIFEXITED(status)) {
                            if ((status=WEXITSTATUS(status)) != FAILEDEXEC) {
                                if(waitprev==1){
                                    waitstatus = -1;
                                } else if(waitprev==2) {
                                    waitstatus = -2;
                                } else {
                                    waitstatus = 0;
                                }
                                printf(VERT("exit status of ["));
                                for (ps = tabcmd; *ps; ps++) printf("%s ", *ps);
                                printf(VERT("\b]=%d\n"), status);
                                //printf("\n");
                                statusproc.value=status;
                                statusproc.failed=0;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            statusproc.failed=1;
                            puts(ROUGE("Abnormal exit"));
                        }
                    } else {
                        printf("Command fork:");
                        for (ps = tabcmd; *ps; ps++) printf("-1-%s", *ps);
                        printf("\n" );
                        if((waitstatus==-1 && status==0) || (waitstatus==-2 && status!=0) ||(waitstatus==0 && status==0)){
                            traiterCmdInFork(tabcmd);
                        } else {
                            //stop le fils quand on ne doit pas executer commande
                            exit(DONTEXEC);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

EDIT2: I added an int arg to `traiterCmdInFork` which egal the number of arg of the cmd ( ls -a = 2) so i only copy where there is text, it solved my problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would say that very much depends on how you are splitting the input into individual words. You should make some attempt to debug that function before you ask for help, and bear in mind that we cannot helpnyou without a [mcve] which precisely illustrates the error.

Comment: I edited and added my full code and tried to explain with a example, hope it's better.
I have try to solve it but i can't find any solution :/

Comment: btw, the `char` given to `isspace` and such must be cast to `unsigned char`, otherwise undefined behaviour happens for bytes >= 128

Comment: You don't initiaise `tab` in `traiterCmdInFork`, so it won't have a `NULL`  at the end as required by `execvp`.

Comment: Notes: 1) that is way too much code to write before making sure that there are no bugs. 2) learn to use the standard library. `strtok` is a lot easier. 3) `valgrind` probably would have told you about that issue. `gdb` is also pretty useful.

Comment: Also: `memset(command,0,strlen(command));` makes very little sense. Think about how `strlen` works (and particularly if its argument is uninitialised).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i changed that char to unsigned char.

Didn't know about valgrind, i will try it :)
I dont think i could have use strtok in this case because i need to separate cmd with ; && or || and to know which one was use